# How can I apply all the possible colour space in CV2 (274 available colour space..?) to a single image and output 274 variations of the image?

Tags: python, loops, colors, space, opencv

Here is my code, help me with problem on title.

```
import cv2
import imutils


image = cv2.imread("/home/taral/Desktop/blister_main/blister.jpg")


flags = [i for i in dir(cv2) if i.startswith('COLOR_')] # color space lists provided by OpenCV2 documentation
count = 1

for flag in flags:
    # holder = ('cv2.{}'.format(flag))
    mode = 'cv2.' + str(flag)
    converted = cv2.cvtColor(image, eval(mode))
    name = '/home/taral/Desktop/blister_main/color_space'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    path = cv2.imwrite(name, converted)
    count += 1
```

How can I apply all the possible colour space in CV2 (274 available colour space..?) to a single image and output 274 variations of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your image read by cv2 so its channels will arrange like Blue-Green-Red, so you can only use `cv2.cvtColor` with BGR related `mode` (E.g: `cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab`).

The error will appear in gray mode (E.g: `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR555`), because gray image only have 1 channel, and the output will wrong at other mode with 3 channels such as RGB, HSV, etc.